# InterBase 7.5 + php

Tags: php, interbase

Всем доброго дня. У меня есть база на `InterBase 7.5`. Я хочу использовать ее данные в веб-программу, через `php`.    
Если честно у меня время в обрез, поэтому сразу вспомнила, про мастером программирование.

Прошу вас, скажите с чего мне начать?

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.ibase.php

Comment: В php.ini я раскоммен. extision=php_interbase.dll, и в php/ext/php_interbase.dll есть. Но когда пример делаю, пишет Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect() in D:\xampp\htdocs\zarplata\test.php on line 8. Что я пропустила? помогите....